# Return View() returns action result method name rather than url

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc

i'm using multiple submit buttons to handle different ways of submitting a form via the asp-action tag helper (i also used the html5 formaction method with the same result).
it correctly hits the controller method, but when i do my own custom validation on the model and added modelstate errors and pass back to the original view the URL changes to the controller method i've called rather than the original view.

here is an example of my code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">@actionLabel</button>
<button asp-action="EditMethod2" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">@actionLabel</button>

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditMethod2(myEditModel 
{
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, resultMessage);

if (ModelState.IsValid && TryValidateModel(
{
   ..// update model and perform something special to EditMethod2
   return RedirectToAction(nameof(EditMyModel), new { id = id });
}
// oh dear we have errors we need to display to the user.
return View(nameof(EditMyModel), myEditModel);
```

the url returned with the correct model errors changes from **MyModel/EditMyModel/79706** to **/MyModel/EditMethod2**

everything is working fine but just url changes to the name of the action i'm calling rather than the redirected view.  how should i be handling this properly? should i pass the ModelState as tempdata via RedirectToAction?

thanks!

.NET core 1.1

Comment: try to return this way  `return View(myEditModel);`

Comment: EditMethod2 isn't a view.  hence the redirection back to original edit